# CodingKeyRepresentable for singleValueContainer

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, codable

I'm a little stuck here. I have a struct with several fields codable to a string (below is similar example):

```
struct MyColor {
  var red: UInt8
  var green: UInt8
  var blue: UInt8
}

extension MyColor: Codable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let value = try container.decode(String.self)
    self = try MyColor.from(string: value) // <- Creates MyColor from string like "#001122"
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encode(stringValue) // <- Converts MyColor to string like "#121212"
  }
}
```

This works fine until I want to encode a `[MyColor: String]` dictionary. Default implementation produced unkeyed array:

```
["#121212", "Hello", "#112233", "Bye"]
```

while I want keyed object:

```
{
  "#121212": "Hello",
  "#112233": "Bye"
}
```

I found this is possible if a type conforms to `CodingKeyRepresentable`, but this requires me to add a `CodingKey`, and this is where I stop following the way to implement it.

Is there a way to archive both: encoding multiple values into single string, and using this string as a key for keyed json representation?

Comment: "and this is where I stop following the way to implement it" Well why did you stop?

Comment: cause I want to use `MyColor` as a string key, and not to have `MyColor` encoded with some other CodingKey. Or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleValueContainer` cannot work because – as the name implies – it handles the **value** of a dictionary, not the key.

Implementing `CodingKeyRepresentable` is not that hard. You need a helper struct to create a `CodingKey`. This is the shortest form

```
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?
    
    init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}
```

You need also an init method in `MyColor` with signature `init(from string: String)` which replaces the static `MyColor.from(string: String)` method. The implementation of `CodingKeyRepresentable` is

```
extension MyColor: CodingKeyRepresentable {
    var codingKey: CodingKey {
        AnyCodingKey(stringValue: stringValue)!
    }
    
    init?<T>(codingKey: T) where T : CodingKey {
        self.init(from: codingKey.stringValue)
    }
}
```

Conforming to `Codable` is not needed if `MyColor` doesn't represent a **value**

Comment: I think `AnyCodingKey` did the trick, yet I keep `Codable` because the type appears somewhere else as a value.